# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: cxf, websphere-8

I am using websphere 8.5.5.5 on windows Server 2008 R2. I am trying to use apache cxf webservices but its giving me error
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found.

Can anyone provide details what should I do to run apache cxf webservice?
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace? Have you tried http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-ForWebSphere6.1.0.29+,V7andV8? Which cxf version are you using?

Comment: Issue is solved using Axis 2 webservice in place of apache cxf. But I will post the full stacktrace